# Why can't java find the JUnit framework?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, junit

I am trying to get a test class compiling with JUnit, and I can't figure out why it will not compile.

I have the following lines at the top of my class:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.*;
```

And the error I am getting is

```
package org.junit does not exist
```

JUnit.jar is currently located in Program Files\JUnit\junit.jar, which currently also resides in my class path. I am working on Windows Vista if that helps.

Any ideas on how I can compile this test class with JUnit?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of JUnit are you using?

I think that until JUnit 3, the package was different:

```
 import junit.framework.*;
```

Also, if you are using Eclipse, you can pick the JUnit framework to use.